# Building OpenCV codes on ROS

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi im new to ROS and openCV.

Im currently running on Ubuntu.

Im currently trying to use Asus Xtion Pro to detect lines using Hough transform detection codes. I have OpenCV 2.4.9 installed and ROS installed. How can i go about building codes to detect lines using my Asus Xtion pro.

Thanks in advance!

Azl

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188523/building-opencv-codes-on-ros/) by [Azl](https://answers.ros.org/users/19895/azl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [cv_bridge Convert between ROS Images and OpenCV Images](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) tutorial. This shows you how you can get a OpenCV representation of image data. Once you have that, you can perform all OpenCV operations on the image data, including hough transform.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Azl](https://answers.ros.org/users/19895/azl/) on 2014-08-01**:
Thank you I will get to it